# In C, is '==' ever used in variable assignment?

Tags: c, syntax

Was working with some SASL code today and noticed the `==` in the below snippet. I'm no C expert but the only way I've ever used that operator was to test equality. Bug?

```
    if ( !conn ) {
        rc == LDAP_SUCCESS;
        goto done;
}
```

Comment: probably a bug.

Comment: This is a bug. There is no reason for this code to exist. Although, to answer the question in it's totality, operator `==` could be used in assignment, for example `int success = (rc == LDAP_SUCCESS)`

Comment: If you actually compile the code, you'll see warnings. Treat warnings as errors - and you have your bug. :)

Comment: `rc == LDAP_SUCCESS;` is a NOP.

Comment: Pay attention: don't blindly replace `rc == LDAP_SUCCESS` with `rc = LDAP_SUCCESS` (which may remove a warning), but check how `rc` is used after the `done` label and act accordingly.

Comment: For the record, overloading the operator in C++ *could* give it a side effect in code that *looked* like C.  It would generally be considered a bad idea, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That statement does nothing. It's a bug.

Now, you COULD assign (rc == LDAP_SUCCESS) to a variable, which would store the boolean result of that operation (1 if true, or 0 if false).